# "Imitation jewelry" or "costume jewelry"

Tags: word-choice, nouns, british-english, translation, collocation

I've looked up the translation of the word *bisutería* in Spanish and it translated to *imitation jewelry* or *costume jewelry*. Which of the two is mostly used in British English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Costume jewellery](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/costume-jewellery)* is what is commonly used and not *imitation jewellery*.